# Creating a popup menu within a fragment.e4xmi for an editor at extension point org.eclipse.ui.editors

Tags: contextmenu, e4, eclipse-fragment

I am creating a custom editor via the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.editors`.
This works all well. Let's say this is given the id=`my.custom.editor.id`

Now, I would like to define a popup menu for my editor within my fragment.e4xmi.
I do not seem to get this to work. I tried creating a `menuContribution` with the Parent-ID:`my.custom.editor.id`, but when I try to activate the menu in my editor with `menuService.registerContextMenu`, I can see that no menu is associated to my editor part.

What is the correct way to create such a context menu?

Comment: What sort of editor? What does it extend? Things like TextEditor have existing code to set up menus and you have to work with them.

Comment: @greg-449 I am extending `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart`

Comment: I believe `EMenuService.registerContextMenu` only looks for menus defined in the current MPart. I don't know if there is a way to set that up for the legacy part used by old style editors.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your assessment. I changed my editor to a native e4 part by using the `IEditorLauncher` interface.